# How to toggle class when click button in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggle class to `button`, and `nav`.

This is what I tried.

```
import React from 'react';
  
class About extends React.Component{
  render(){ 
    return (
    <>
      <button className={`btn-toggle ${show ? "btn-active" : ""}`}>>
        Toggle
      </button>
      <nav className={`nav-toggle ${show ? "nav-active" : ""}`}>menu</nav>
    </>
    )
  }
}
export default About;
```

What do I need to do ?

Comment: Use state to store a value in "show" and a click handler to change it?

Comment: There is no event handler to change the value of `show`. You should add a `onClick` event on a button to modify the value of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this but Im not sure why are want to toggle button because you always need to have something shown on which you can click and display nav. But as its metioned, it's not good practise to change classes

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
  
const About = () => {
   const [navVisible, setNavVisible] = useState(false);
   const [btnVisible, setBtnVisible] = useState(true);

    return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setNavVisible(!navVisible)} className={`btn-toggle ${show ? "btn-active" : ""}`}>>
        Toggle
      </button>
      <nav className={`nav-toggle ${navVisible ? "nav-active" : ""}`}>menu</nav>
    </>
    )
}
export default About;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not a good practice to change classes"? It's done all the time.